# Unable to create DB in cosmos emulator

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have been trying to test my changes using cosmos db emulator. I kept getting exception, service unavailable. Tried via the explorer and got the same error:

```
{"code":500,"body":{"code":"InternalServerError","message":"Service is currently unavailable, please retry after a while. If this problem persists please contact support.\r\nActivityId: e7204d29-793e-4490-9916-6138fad1b715, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.9.2"},"headers":{"content-type":"application/json","date":"Wed, 12 Feb 2020 17:53:44 GMT","server":"Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0","x-ms-activity-id":"e7204d29-793e-4490-9916-6138fad1b715","x-ms-gatewayversion":"version=2.9.2","x-ms-throttle-retry-count":0,"x-ms-throttle-retry-wait-time-ms":0},"activityId":"e7204d29-793e-4490-9916-6138fad1b715"}
```

Comment: This is a issue related produce issue,i suggest you opening a case on the github:https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-db-emulator-docker/issues so that you could get official answer ASAP. Or you could contact azure cosmos db team directly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you confirmed the emulator is running? Also, please edit your question to show your relevant code, including connection details to the emulator. Otherwise, I'm not sure this is answerable.

Comment: Have you already went through the Troubleshooting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#troubleshooting ?

Comment: Thanks @MatiasQuaranta resetting the data helped :)

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to apply "Reset Data..." on the context menu of the Emulator tray icon:

[image: Emulator context menu]

This error often occurs if you already filled all the possible data partitions in the Emulator and are trying to create more collections or if an Emulator update might have corrupted data.

Related troubleshooting guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#troubleshooting